# How to get excel column with the column index in NPOI C#

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I want to set the cell formula for columns k-P by using a loop and in c# i can only loop with integers, how do you actually get the column(E.G K,L,M,N,O,P) with the index? for looping through rows its pretty easy because they are just numbers but for columns excel uses letters.
I cant think of anything other than defining my own List for letters k-P  in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CellReference`, if you already have the cell object.

```
var temp = new CellReference(cell);
var reference = temp.FormatAsString();
```

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Allso you can get it directly from ICell object:

```
var adress = cell.Address.FormatAsString();
```

Ore if you need column name only add method like this:

```
public static string GetColumnName(this ICell cell)
{
    return Regex.Match(cell.Address.FormatAsString(), @"[A-Z]+").Value;
}
```

And then just call it like:

```
var colName = cell.GetColumnName();
```